# Does the VS version setting in Settings.settings matter?

Tags: visual-studio

Looking through the server vs local code on a humongous legacy project, I see this in Settings.settings:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)">
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Name="(Default)" />
  </Profiles>
  <Settings />
</SettingsFile>
```

Is there a problem with having this VS2010 project reference 2004 this way? Or does it not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem.

The "2004" actually is part of the [namespace name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_names), and it is not related with the version of Visual Studio.

Creating a new project with Visual Studio 2012 will create a settings file that references exactly the same namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings`.